# Migrate local Git repo to Visual Studio Online from IDE

Tags: git, visual-studio-2013, azure-devops

I created a new Team Project on Visual Studio Online that I have connected to in Visual Studio 2013. Using the IDE, I cloned a local Git repo (that was pulled down from GitHub) into the Local Git Repositories section.

When I went through the documentation on Visual Studio's [website](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/get-started/share-your-code-in-GIT-vs), it showed an option to "Publish to {Team Project}."

[image]

Mine doesn't show this:

[image]

And it looks like this has been a [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14711796/publish-local-git-repository-to-team-foundation-service) in the past (others have needed to change the .git/config file). Has this been fixed yet so I can use the IDE completely? Or am I missing something?

Comment: You need to connect to a Team Project that has a Git repository, only then can Visual Studio show the publish option. I suspect you also need to add TFS as remote to the local repository by editing the config file or by using the git commandline `git remote remove` and `git remote add`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This publish option is only shown when you are connected to a Team Project and when the remote uri of the git repository is set to the TFS uri.

To fix this you can manually edit the git files, but I tend to open the Git Command Prompt (right-click the repo and choose <kbd>Open Command prompt</kbd>.

On the command line enter:

> `git remote set-url origin http://[server]:[port]/tfs/[projectcollection]/_git/[ProjectName]`
>
> `git pull`
>
> [[ resolve any merge issues ]]
>
> `git push`

Comment: Thanks, jessehouwing. I actually have used Command Prompt to add a remote (it also works to solely use the command-line to pull down the GitHub repo directly then push the changes), but wasn't sure if VS2013 finally supported the migration all in the IDE :(

Answer (score 8):

The answer marked as correct doesn't appear to be correct. To push an existing local repo to a VSO repo involves following:

`git remote add origin https://<NAME>.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_git/<PROJECT>
git push -u origin --all`

This assumes you've already created `<PROJECT>` in VS Online as a new team project using Git as the source control strategy.

Comment: I have created a project on VSO and when I run the second command it gives an error "TF401019: The Git repository with name or identifier VSCodeDemo does not exist or you do not have permissions for the operation you are attempting."