# use local Git repositories in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: git, visual-studio-2012, tfs

I've downloaded the necessary add-ins for Visual Studio 2012 to allow me to set up Git hub local repos.

I cloned some projects from git hub, and I see them in visual studio team explorer as Local Git Repositories.

The problem is: how do I reference these local repositories in my visual studio web project. I want to maintain the reference to the Local Git Repo, not just copy in the javascript files.

Is this my solution: *the remote uri of my local git repo must be set to the TFS uri*? 
[Migrate local Git repo to Visual Studio Online from IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20889686/migrate-local-git-repo-to-visual-studio-online-from-ide)
In which case I def need tfs 2013?

Thanks,
Michael

Comment: Sorry, but I cannot follow what you are trying to do. Do you have a TFS and Git?

Comment: I have a local repo of a project that i cloned from github, and I want to use (debug, makes edits to) that local repo within visual studio.  I want to be able to check in those edits back to Github. I want to be able to use that local repo in multiple Visual studio projects.  My main web  project is source-controlled via TFS - not github.  I have TFS 2012. I have visual studio 2012 with all the necessary Git extensions.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to use TFVC 2012 with the Git client tools use [Git-TF](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30474).
If you wish to migrate from TFVC to Git you need a new Team Project in [Visual Studio Online or TFS 2013](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2013/01/30/getting-started-with-git-in-visual-studio-and-team-foundation-service.aspx) and you will have the full native Git experience.